# Is there any reason for GC to "slow" current execution even though GC logs show it doesn't?

Tags: java, performance, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, jvm

Here is a description of my java program :

> > It is an optimization algorithm that runs for hours in a Thread, that
> >     is often interrupted by the service for querying stuff about the
> >     current optimization.
>
> The optimization routine is a succession of simple operations (let us
>   call it "moves") that are repeated over and over. Sometimes, the
>   optimization procedure will slow down a lot : a move generally takes
>   less than 100ms, and sometimes, it will take several seconds, even
>   minutes.

Of course I thought about GC freezing the execution while performing full GC so I did some experiment and according to GC logs, minor collection are done very regularly and take 10ms, while full GC is very rare and takes no more than 2 seconds. I also ran some analysis via GC log analysis tools and the Throughput hits more than 95%. As an exemple, on a 7 minutes test run, there is only between 2 and 3 seconds lost due to GC according to GC log.

One should conclude GC is not the problem here. However, I observed that trying other GC algorithms would have quite a huge impact on how much time the "worst" moves will take (it can double/triple the execution time of "moves" when it starts to slow down). Therefore, GC seems to have an impact on it, even though GC logs tells me GC is not taking time.

Moreover, I also observe that "moves" tends to slow down in sequence : when one move slows down, the following one has a greater chance to slow down as well, even though they are not related in any way as these operations are fully independant. It just feels like the whole system is slowing down at some times, especially when the service is called a lot.

I read some things about memory fragmentation of heapspace that could lead to major slowing down in applications, and as my moves are creating and destroying a lot of objects, that could explain what I am experiencing here. However, I don't see why GC logs don't show this.

I am really reaching the limits of my knowledge and exeperience here and I would take any intuition or clue you may have to investigate further.

[image: Heapspace profile while running the test]

Comment: Performance is a big can of worms. You need to look at everything surrounding the JVM as well and not just at the GC. When you said you feel the "slow" can you break down the time in regard to from request to response? What is the network time? Processing time? Heap usage and most importantly the CPU%. Often stress test, tested the hardware and not the software. Java is perform well when the CPU is below 80% utilise. Please provide more stats and I am happy to discuss further.

Comment: Everything ran locally on the same computer. CPU stays below 50% depending on the machine. What really slows down is the "move" operation. A move creates a duplicate (.clone()) of an item, applies a modification to it (called "move"), and add it to a stack that has a limited size (first in first out). A move usually takes between 10 and 100ms depending on the move, and when it slows down, it can last from 1s to 1min (10min in the worst cases).

Comment: What is the heap size? can you post your runtime parameters?

Comment: -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -Xloggc:C:/temp/gc.log -Xmx3g

Comment: Ok, so your JVM is using CMS GC. When running your test, you do see the heap increase? Does the young generation space change alot? The downside of using CMS is that when heap builds up, Full GC will take longer to run. Have you tried using other GC? Like parallelOldGC and paralledGC?

Comment: I added a link to the heapspace profile in the description and here is a link towards a GC log analysis : http://gceasy.io/my-gc-report.jsp?p=c2hhcmVkLzIwMTcvMDYvNS8tLWdjLmxvZy0tMTItNTgtMTU= As you can see full gc is quite rare and not that time consuming... I tried all GCs but I thought the default GC in java 8 is ParallelGC ?

Comment: Ok so ParallelGC was used. It also said 13.6% is called by System.gc()? It looks like you got memory leaks? I would expect heap space to remain horizontal and not going up and up? It seems GC or FullGC does not reclaim the original space? I think you should profile the code to see which object take up the space.

Answer (score 0):

Another explanation is that the cause of the slow-down is outside of the Java application.

- It could be due to competition for CPU cycles with other processes.
- It could be due to competition for memory (resulting in paging).
- If you are running in a virtual machine, the resource competition could be between different VMs.

Or, it could be some unexpected behavior in your application:

- Are you using `WeakReference` or `SoftReference` objects.
- Do you use `finalize()` methods?
- Have you tried profiling the application?

I suggest you try using OS-provided performance tools to see if there is other activity on the system that correlated to the pauses.  Also, looks for slowdowns / pauses in the system itself.

Comment: Hi, I am using neither WeakReference nor SoftReference explicitely (I actually discovered it with you post). I take care not to create Objects within loops as much as possible, if that can help. I don't use finalize() methods. What do you mean by "profiling" the application ? I use jvisualvm a lot, as well as GC log analyzers, and I log a lot of stats in my application as well to identify slowdowns : this is why I am confident they happens within "moves", that are of limited complexity and have no reason to take more than a few ms, which plea for some slowdown of the global application.

Comment: @CédricHervet Don't forget paging, it's a common culprit.  I wouldn't bother reducing object creation, at least not now, when everything indicates that GC is not the problem. Try a tool ("top" on Linux, task manager on W) which shows you the process behavior. Are you doing any IO? Is there some synchronization?

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by "paging" ?

Comment: Paging: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging.  Virtual memory: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory